# How can I check with which user the cmd box has been opened?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm facing this issue. when I run an application appearing few cmd boxes thanks to those, after the log in, I can run a bach file that will start a third party application. If I try to run the same bach from the directory I got an error. So I guess the cmd boxes are using a different user.

How can I check with which user the cmd box has been opened? 
I hope the question is clear.

```
[ ] d:\NETA\Software\BusOpt\bin_610>tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v /fo:csv /nh
"cmd.exe","6132","","3","18,548 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","3740","","3","18,548 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","5396","","3","18,548 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","3292","","3","18,548 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","13136","","10","18,580 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","10484","","10","18,580 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","12876","","10","18,580 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","8056","","10","18,580 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","11044","","9","3,152 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","7868","","9","3,152 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","1188","","9","3,152 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","9328","","9","3,136 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","6764","RDP-Tcp#1","6","3,180 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","14516","RDP-Tcp#1","6","3,148 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","14240","RDP-Tcp#1","6","3,184 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","10248","RDP-Tcp#1","6","3,184 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","14196","","35","3,136 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","15120","","35","3,336 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","13216","","35","3,128 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","12376","","35","3,288 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","14116","","35","3,600 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","5012","","35","3,612 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","6436","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,180 K","Running","EURO\AE4","0:00:00","
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
"cmd.exe","11732","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,176 K","Running","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
"cmd.exe","11584","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,316 K","Running","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe - tasklist  /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v /fo:csv /
nh"
"cmd.exe","12488","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,164 K","Running","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
"cmd.exe","14452","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,440 K","Running","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"Administrator: Command Prompt - "cmd.exe" ,"6132","","3","18,548 K","Unknown","
N/A","0:00:00","N/A" - "cmd.exe" ,"3740","","3","1"
"cmd.exe","10372","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,276 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"N/A"
"cmd.exe","15100","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,244 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"N/A"
"cmd.exe","14720","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,244 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"N/A"
"cmd.exe","13896","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,236 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"N/A"
"cmd.exe","6920","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,240 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00","
N/A"
"cmd.exe","6800","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,268 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00","
N/A"
"cmd.exe","14060","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,276 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"N/A"
"cmd.exe","15008","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,276 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"N/A"
"cmd.exe","12752","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,240 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"N/A"
"cmd.exe","7408","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,268 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00","
N/A"
"cmd.exe","12884","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,236 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"N/A"
"cmd.exe","13744","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,272 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"N/A"
"cmd.exe","5592","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,240 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00","
N/A"
"cmd.exe","11944","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,268 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"N/A"
"cmd.exe","12608","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,268 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"N/A"
"cmd.exe","880","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,272 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00","N
/A"
"cmd.exe","14232","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,240 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"N/A"
"cmd.exe","2088","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,268 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00","
N/A"
"cmd.exe","1032","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,244 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00","
N/A"
"cmd.exe","13044","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,236 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"N/A"
"cmd.exe","15220","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,276 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"N/A"
"cmd.exe","3648","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,244 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00","
N/A"
"cmd.exe","9692","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,272 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00","
N/A"
"cmd.exe","8864","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,276 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00","
N/A"
"cmd.exe","6384","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,276 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00","
N/A"
"cmd.exe","10916","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,244 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"N/A"
"cmd.exe","8232","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,360 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00","
N/A"
"cmd.exe","8032","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,280 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00","
N/A"
"cmd.exe","10812","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,152 K","Unknown","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"N/A"
```

Comment: I run the following cmd tasklist : _"cmd.exe","5012","","35","3,612 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A"
"cmd.exe","6436","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,180 K","Running","EURO\AE4","0:00:00","
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
"cmd.exe","11732","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,176 K","Running","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
"cmd.exe","11584","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,284 K","Running","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe - tasklist  /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v /fo:csv /
nh"
"cmd.exe","12488","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,164 K","Running","EURO\AE4","0:00:00",
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from cmdline:

```
for /f "tokens=1,8,10 delims=," %a in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v /fo:csv /nh') do echo %~a %~b %~c
```

The above line will print the command name, owner and the Windows title of each cmd.exe process currently running. As an example, I ran it with some different window titles on my lapotop and you will get:

```
cmd.exe DOMAIN\Gbarnard Command Prompt
cmd.exe DOMAIN\Gbarnard C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
cmd.exe DOMAIN\Gbarnard Command Prompt
cmd.exe DOMAIN\Gbarnard C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe - test_number.cmd
```

To run the exact same line in batch file, double on th `%` like below:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,8,10 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v /fo:csv /nh') do echo %%~a %%~b %%~c
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried to run the cmd you suggested I got this result:                                                 
d:\users\E4>for /f "tokens=1,7,9 delims=," %a in ('tasklist /fi "imagename
eq cmd.exe" /v /fo:csv /nh') do echo %~a %~b %~c

d:\users\E4>echo cmd.exe Running 0:00:00
cmd.exe Running 0:00:00

d:\users\E4>echo cmd.exe Unknown 0:00:00                                                                  I have no idea what is that. but I'm sure it's not what I was looking for :D

Comment: I try to remake the question.I know that the cmdline could be opened with a different user. since those prompts are automatically opened by the application I don't know which user the application is using for opening them.

Comment: @Gabriele Please do this from cmdline, and copy the output to you question please. `tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v /fo:csv /nh`

Comment: I run the following cmd tasklist : _"cmd.exe","5012","","35","3,612 K","Unknown","N/A","0:00:00","N/A" "cmd.exe","6436","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,180 K","Running","EURO\AE4","0:00:00"," C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" "cmd.exe","11732","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,176 K","Running","EURO\AE4","0:00:00", "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" "cmd.exe","11584","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,284 K","Running","EURO\AE4","0:00:00", "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe - tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v /fo:csv / nh" "cmd.exe","12488","RDP-Tcp#3","7","3,164 K","Running","EURO\AE4","0:00:00", "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"_

Comment: **"EURO\AE4"** it's my user I suppose that your tips working. but now I have no clue why I can run that batch file only from the cmdline that the application opens automatically instead directly from the directory.

Comment: ok, firstly, your user is EURO\AE4, secondly, I edited the code so that it will display correctly now, for some reason your numeric number also has a comma, shich is what I split by. So please retry the code.

Comment: My code is working, but seems some of your batches run with unknown user.